Проблема с созданием базы данных в тг боте
Вот часть кода:
def db_table_val (user_id: int, username: str, priglasil_id):
    conn = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(f"select count(*) from apple where user_id = {user_id}")
    if username != None:
        if cursor.fetchone()[0] == 0:
            cursor.execute('INSERT INTO apple (user_id, username, priglasil_id) VALUES (?,?,?)', (user_id, username, priglasil_id,))
            conn.commit()

Вот ошибка:
in start_msg
    db_table_val(user_id=us_id, username=username, priglasil_id = priglasil_id)
  File "c:\Users\Татьяна\Desktop\fff\[f.ggdt.ru]casino-bot\apple_functions.py", line 22, in db_table_val
    cursor.execute(f"select count(*) from apple where user_id = {user_id}")
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: apple
PS C:\Users\Татьяна\Desktop\fff> 

А вот часть кода где показана первая ошибка:
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_msg(message):
  conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db', check_same_thread=False)
  cursor = conn.cursor()
  us_id = message.from_user.id
  username = message.from_user.username
  if " " in message.text:
    try:
      priglasil_id = message.text.split()[1]
      priglasil_id = int(priglasil_id)
      if us_id != priglasil_id:
        user = get_all_users(priglasil_id)
      else:
        priglasil_id = None
    except:
     priglasil_id = None
  else:
    priglasil_id = None
  conn.close()
  db_table_val(user_id=us_id, username=username, priglasil_id = priglasil_id)



sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: apple

Нужно создать таблицу apple в базе данных database.db
Один раз запустить скрипт:
import sqlite3


with sqlite3.connect('database.db') as conn:
    conn.execute(''' CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS apple (
                    user_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                    username TEXT NOT NULL,
                    priglasil_id INTEGER
                    )  ''')

в рабочем каталоге.

Спасибо большое, помогло, Вы не могли бы дать мне свой тг у меня просто еще есть вопросы, вот мой  @Overstime

Задавайте здесь, если ответ помог, можете отметить решением.

Теперь вот такая ошибка:
in menu_keyboard
cursor.execute("SELECT admin FROM apple WHERE user_id = ('%s')"%(us_id))
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: admin

У вас в таблице нет поля admin. Его надо добавить  при создании таблицы: ''' CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS apple(user_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, username TEXT NOT NULL, priglasil_id INTEGER, admin TEXT)  '''. Если admin - число, то замените TEXT на INTEGER

Спасибо помогло, а вот здесь как:
cursor.execute(f"select count(*) from apple where user_id = {user_id}")
sqlite3.DatabaseError: database disk image is malformed
